# How to arrange Array in Ascending Order JS

Tags: javascript

Im trying to do selection sort on array, i dont see whats the problem to the code below i tried implementing it in c++ and it works but it does now work when i try it in javascript

```js
function selection(array, size) {
  var x;
  var y;
  var min;

  for (x = 0; x < size - 1; x++) {
    min = x;

    for (y = 0; y < size; y++) {
      if (array[y] > array[min]) {
        min = y;

        var z = 0;
        z = array[min]
        array[min] = array[x];
        array[x] = z;
      }
    }
  }
  return array, size;
}
```

Comment: Proper indentation would make this easier to read/understand.

Comment: Can you provide more detail than "does now work"?

Comment: You can't return two variables from a function. `return array, size` won't return both `array` and `size`, only `size` will be returned

Comment: Do not assume that code which works in c++ will work automatically in JS. They're different languages

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function selection(array, size) {
  if (size > array.length) {
    return 'Size is bigger than array length!';
  }
  
  if (size < 0 || typeof size !== 'number') {
    return 'Invalid size';
  }

  let min;

  for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    min = x;

    for (let y = x + 1; y < size; y++) {
      if (array[y] > array[min]) {
        min = y;
      }
    }
    
    if (min !== x) {
      [array[x], array[min]] = [array[min], array[x]];
    } 
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(selection([9, 3, 5, 4 , 8], 5));
console.log(selection([1, 9, 5, 8], 3));
console.log(selection([9, 3, 5], 2));
console.log(selection([9, 3], 5));
console.log(selection([9, 3], 'p'));
```